# How to get data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 base on ID?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How to get input data (ID) from Userfrom and get the value from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2? I found this link http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/interactive-userform.html but only work in single sheet.

Example of sheet 1

[image]

The Value I need is:

Column A from (Sheet 1) to Column C3 in (Sheet 2)
Column B from (Sheet 1) to Column E8 in (Sheet 2)
Column C from (Sheet 1) to Column G3 in (Sheet 2)

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Why is Column B in Sheet2!E8?

Comment: Find() or Match()  would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Column A from (Sheet 1) to Column C3 in (Sheet 2) =Sheet1!A:A
2. Column B from (Sheet 1) to Column E8 in (Sheet 2) =Sheet1!B:B
3. Column C from (Sheet 1) to Column G3 in (Sheet 2) =Sheet1!C:C

Answer (score 0):

In your link they use construction like:

```
Cells("coordinates here").Value = your_values
```

Which in this context equal to

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells("coordinates here").Value = your_values
```

So you should make your output like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells("coordinates here").Value = your output
```